# Change HTML on $(window).width();

Tags: jquery, html, resize, window, width

I have a three-column header bar. When the window is less than 767px in width, I want to alter the HTML of the three columns.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="col-xs-4" id="tab1">Original Text</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4" id="tab2">Original Text</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4" id="tab2">Original Text</div>
</div>
```

and the **JS:**

```
if ($(window).width() < 767 {
    $("#tab1").text('New Text');
    $("#tab2").text('New Text');
    $("#tab3").text('New Text');
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 767) {
        $("#tab1").text('New Text');
        $("#tab2").text('New Text');
        $("#tab3").text('New Text');
    }
});
```

....Talk to me!

Comment: you can find one syntax error with this line.. `if ($(window).width() < 767 {`

Comment: You have error in code. you have not closed if statement

Comment: What is your problem, is it not working define the `error`.

Answer (score 0):

you missed if closing bracket "**)**"

```
if ($(window).width() < 767){
//your code
}
```